# Raspberry Pi 3B+ doesnt boot from USB on 23.10 Mantic

Tags: raspberrypi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, booting from a hdd drive plugged on USB.
Been running several versions of Ubuntu fine with this, I was lately running 22.04.

Tried to upgrade to 23.10, but Ubuntu crashes during the boot sequence.
If I create a SD card with 23.10, Ubuntu runs fine.
If I copy same SD card to hdd, Ubuntu refuses to boot.

I don't think it's an issue with the way I copy the sd-card to the hdd.
I followed the same process multiple times over the last few days with 22.04, no problem at all.

If I mount the hdd when booting with the SD Card, I cannot see any changes in the logs in /var/log, looks like Ubuntu was unable to mount the drive (or that something fails before that).

Any idea what it could be, or at least how I could get logs to check?

Thanks in advance :)

Aurelien